# Error in Firebase Installation within Inoic 4+ Web App

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, ionic-framework, npm

I want to connect my ionic application with firebase to perform storing and retrieving of data and to perform authentication. 
I'm using npm package as **npm install firebase**
but still, I'm getting an error.
The error is like

```
> grpc@1.24.2 install C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc
> node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library

node-pre-gyp WARN Using request for node-pre-gyp https download
node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for grpc@1.24.2 and node@10.15.3 (node-v64 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error self signed certificate in certificate chain
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:153:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library" "--module=C:\\Users\\radhika.thakkar\\Desktop\\projects\\coursera\\ionic\\ionic-firebase-crud\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\\grpc_node.node" "--module_name=grpc_node" "--module_path=C:\\Users\\radhika.thakkar\\Desktop\\projects\\coursera\\ionic\\ionic-firebase-crud\\node_modules\\grpc\\src\\node\\extension_binary\\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown" "--napi_version=3" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v64"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc
gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc\node_modules\node-pre-gyp\lib\util\compile.js:83:29)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:189:13)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:970:16)
node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
node-pre-gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17763
node-pre-gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\radhika.thakkar\\Desktop\\projects\\coursera\\ionic\\ionic-firebase-crud\\node_modules\\grpc\\node_modules\\node-pre-gyp\\bin\\node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build" "--library=static_library"
node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc
node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v10.15.3
node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.14.0
node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
Failed to execute 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --library=static_library --module=C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown\grpc_node.node --module_name=grpc_node --module_path=C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\Desktop\projects\coursera\ionic\ionic-firebase-crud\node_modules\grpc\src\node\extension_binary\node-v64-win32-x64-unknown --napi_version=3 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v64' (1)
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\watchpack\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\karma\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9 (node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.1 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! grpc@1.24.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the grpc@1.24.2 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-08T04_37_38_130Z-debug.log
```

so anyone can help me out to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this and then install firebase

```
npm install -g node-gyp

npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

If this doesnt work, try setting python path via npm config

```
npm config set python "c:\Python\27\python.exe"
```

Comment: when I'm trying to install *npm install --global --production windows-build-tools* this package, I got an error like
`Downloading Python failed. Error: { Error: self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1051:34)`

Comment: try this on cmd and then install again 

>> set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Comment: I used this command  set NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 
but still i'm getting an error like 

`
C:\Windows\system32>npm install --global --production windows-build-tools

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\radhika.thakkar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js



Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
Downloading Python failed. Error: Error: SSL Error: SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN
`

Comment: Remove  %USERPROFILE%\.windows-build-tools\
Run with Administrator access CMD 

 npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools